# how to integrate $ \int \sin(\pi nt^2)\cos(\pi mt)\, dt $

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I integrate 
$$
\int \sin(\pi nt)\cos(\pi mt)\, dt
$$

I tried to put it into complex form then integrating it but I am not getting a correct answer.

Comment: I put the integral from your title into the body of the question, using MathJax formatting; can you confirm that it's correct?

Comment: The integral in the title is not the same as the integral in the body. Which do you want us to help you with?

Comment: The original title was "sin(ntpit)cos(mtpi) dt". I wasn't sure if the extra $t$ in the $\sin$ factor was supposed to be there or not, so I kept it there as $t^2$; Lovsovs edited it out of the integral in the body.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Notice that $$\begin{cases}\sin(\alpha+\beta) = \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta) \\ \sin(\alpha-\beta) = \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) - \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta) \end{cases}$$
Therefore, $$\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) = \dfrac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)+\sin(\alpha-\beta)}{2}$$
And the integral you want to compute reduces to $$\int \sin(\pi nt)\cos(\pi mt) dt = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\int \sin(\pi(n+m)t) dt + \int \sin(\pi (n-m)t)dt\right)$$